# SharePoint 2007: Single Sign-on Anomaly

Tags: sharepoint-2007, windows-server-2008, single-sign-on

I have a Virtual Machine running the following:

- Windows Server 2008
- SharePoint 2007
- SP1  Exchange 2007
- Dynamics Axapta 2009

I have started the Single Sign On Service and configured it properly. Central Administration is running on HTTPS bound to a specific IP address as a new site in IIS. When I click on the link to manage the server in Central Administration for Single Sign On it keeps redirecting to localhost even when typing the complete Uri in the Address bar. Any idea what is causing this behaviour and how to get around it?

I need to configure this for BDC connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research it turns out that there is no solution or explanation for this happening. I have since rebuilt the virtual environment and configured SSO before creating the SSL sites and doing the IP binding.